# Experience cloud sfdx deploying issues

Tags: salesforcedx, digital-experience

I've got pretty new repo and trying to deploy all of ExperienceBundle contents to scratch org. Always i get an error
`You seem to be missing the property **isLockerServiceEnabled** in Сourses Staging/config/mainAppPage.json`
But documentaton says that we are able to find that property only in **sitename.json**
What i should check to be sure that repo is correct?

Comment: Is mainAppPage a Lightning component or Page? If so Can you check the API version of it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug either in the current metadata API version or in current SFDX version.
I have this attribute In the source code for my Experience Bundle:

```
 "isLockerServiceEnabled" : true,
```

Then on making declarative changes and retrieving those changes in the Experience Bundle the attribute is removed.

If I try to safe the result (unmodified from what was just retrieved), then if fails with the error

```
You seem to be missing the property isLockerServiceEnabled in site_X/config/mainAppPage.json with component ID: ...
```

My solution for now is to add this line to each 'mainAppPage.json'.

```
"isLockerServiceEnabled" : true,
```

I will see if there is a suitable place to report the bug to get a comprehensive answer. I stumbled upon this post while looking.